# datePicker() method not getting in Material DatePicker

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, datepickerdialog

I am getting error while `datePicker()` function find in Material Datepicker. Below is error code;

[image]

I used below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot comment because of my reputation, Use this code for Java

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

Builder datePicker should be called statically,

Change

> MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = new
>   MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()

to

> val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()

and build it

> val picker = builder.build()

after that, you can show it easily with

> picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())

You can implement listeners with picker,

> picker.addOnCancelListener {
>   Log.d("DatePicker Activity", "Dialog was cancelled")    }